# Windows IIS server subdomain through port 80 to point to subroute

Tags: iis, subdomain, macos-windowserver

I have two subdomains which are pointing to the same server:

- kon.balaghlb.com -> 80.208.224.173
- grahhic.balaghlb.com -> 80.208.224.173

I want to handle the two on port 80 inorder to be pointing like this:

- kon.balaghlb.com -> 80.208.224.173/kon
- grahhic.balaghlb.com -> 80.208.224.173/graphic

I tried to play around with inbound rules without no luck.

Any help how to acheive these routes on windows server with iis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve your requirement you could try below steps:

- Open the IIS Manager
- In the Connections pane on the left side, expand your server's name and select the website
- In the middle pane, find the **URL Rewrite** feature and double-click on it.
- On the right-hand pane, click on "Add Rule(s)..."
- Choose “Blank Rule” under the “Inbound Rules” section and click "OK."
- Add rule as shown below:

[image]

Repeat same steps for the another site and use rewrite url as "/graphic/{R:1}"

Make sure you have a single website set up in IIS where you'll be hosting both subdomains and you should have the sub-folders `kon` and `graphic` in site root folder.

Comment: the pattern is kon\.balaghlb\.com, which works, the second approch didnt work as it gave 500 error, please modify to upvote and mark it as answered. Thank you dear

Comment: @AbdallahSafieddine thanks for sharing the update , just would like to double confirm the url rewrite rule with the patter kon\.balaghlb\.com  approach worked for you and adding the site did not wokred. correct me if i am wrong

Comment: Yes likeyou said, the second approach gave an internal server error

Comment: @AbdallahSafieddine thanks for the conformation. post is updated now